# out of phase data in form value using useSelector

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux-thunk

good evening

I am making an excercise, just a simple CRUD fetching data using redux-thunk.
I want to modified a selected item and show field data and then manipulate the values.
For that I have a custom hook called useForm:

```
import { useState } from "react"

export const useForm = (initialState = {}) => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)

    const reset = () => {
        setValues(initialState)
    }

    const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {

        setValues({
            ...values,
            [target.name]: target.value
        })


    }

    return [values, handleInputChange, reset]
```

and this my UpdateItem component (I know that to refactor is a must):

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'

import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm'
import { baseURL } from '../configuration/baseURL'

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { types } from '../types/types';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import Swal from 'sweetalert2'


export default function UpdateItem() {

    const history = useHistory()

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { selected } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer)
    const { data } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer)

    const id = selected?.id

    const selectedItemtoModify = data?.filter(x => x?.id === id)
    console.log(data !== undefined && selectedItemtoModify)

    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.name)
    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.cost)
    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.department[0].name)
    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.department[0].identification)
    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.category[0].name)
    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.category[0].id)

    const name = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.name
    const cost = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.cost
    const departmentName = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.department[0].name
    const departmentIdentification = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.department[0].identification
    const categoryName = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.category[0].name
    const categoryId = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.category[0].id


    const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({

        newName: name,
        newCost: cost,
        newDepartmentName: departmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification: departmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName: categoryName,
        newCategoryId: categoryId
    })

    const {
        newName,
        newCost,
        newDepartmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName,
        newCategoryId } = formValues

    const handleUpdateItem = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            await axios.put(`${baseURL}${id}`, {
                "id": +id,
                "name": newName,
                "cost": +newCost,
                "department": [
                    {
                        "name": newDepartmentName,
                        "identification": newDepartmentIdentification
                    }
                ],
                "category": [
                    {
                        "name": newCategoryName,
                        "id": +newCategoryId
                    }
                ]
            })
            const modified = await axios.get(`${baseURL}${id}`)
            const { data } = modified

            dispatch({
                type: types.modify,
                modifiedItem: data
            });
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Your item has been modified',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                history.push('/')
            }, 1500);

        } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Something went wrong!',
                footer: 'Unable to modify item, who passes the id?'
            })
            return dispatch({
                type: types.error,
                msg: 'Unable to modify item'
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='container mb-5 pb-3 bg-light'>
            <form className='mt-3' onSubmit={handleUpdateItem}>

                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Name'
                    placeholder='Name'
                    name='newName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Cost'
                    placeholder='Cost'
                    name='newCost'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCost}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Department Name'
                    placeholder='Department Name'
                    name='newDepartmentName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newDepartmentName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Department Identification'
                    placeholder='Department Identification'
                    name='newDepartmentIdentification'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newDepartmentIdentification}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Category Name'
                    placeholder='Category Name'
                    name='newCategoryName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCategoryName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Category Id'
                    placeholder='Category Id'
                    name='newCategoryId'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCategoryId}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />

                <button className='btn btn-success ' type=' submit'>
                    Modify Item
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and this is the reducer:

```
import { types } from "../types/types";

const initialState = {
    data: null,
    selected: null,
    deleted: '',
    created: null,
    modified: null,
    error: ''
}

export const axiosDataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.get:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.data
            }
        case types.selected:
            return {
                ...state,
                selected: action.selectedItem
            }
        case types.delete:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: state.data.filter(item => item.id !== action.deletedItem.id),
                deleted: action.deletedItem
            }
        case types.created:
            return {
                ...state,
                created: action.createdItem
            }
        case types.modified:
            return {
                ...state,
                modified: action.modifiedItem
            }

        case types.error:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.msg
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

everithing is ok, but, when I select an option from a table:

[table fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN4wW.png)

It doesn't work as expected because there is a delay fetching the data and the form has no value on it at first, BUT after the value is obtained but not showing in the form:
[first nothing then updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpf2Q.png)

I can introduce some other values, and submit those values and works perfect

and then when I select some other field it shows the previous value instead of the actual selected by me value:
[I've selected Raspberries and I obtain Cherries as console.log show...and it keeps going](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enI2m.png)

What about this out of phase data obtaining? @Shyam https://stackoverflow.com/users/8884388/shyam?

EDITED
I've made this change in my UpdateItem.js component, the result still the same:
How can I wait for selected to be fully loaded??

```
    const { selected } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer)

    console.log(selected)

    console.log(selected?.name)
    console.log(selected?.cost)
    console.log(selected?.department[0].name)
    console.log(selected?.department[0].identification)
    console.log(selected?.category[0].name)
    console.log(selected?.category[0].id)

    const id = selected?.id
    const name = selected?.name
    const cost = selected?.cost
    const departmentName = selected?.department[0].name
    const departmentIdentification = selected?.department[0].identification
    const categoryName = selected?.category[0].name
    const categoryId = selected?.category[0].id
```

EDITING WITH MY SOLUTION
what i did:

I split component in two:
UpdateItem.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'

import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm'
import { baseURL } from '../configuration/baseURL'

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { types } from '../types/types';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import Swal from 'sweetalert2'


export default function UpdateItem({ id, name, cost, departmentName, departmentIdentification, categoryName, categoryId }) {

    const history = useHistory()

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({

        newName: name,
        newCost: cost,
        newDepartmentName: departmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification: departmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName: categoryName,
        newCategoryId: categoryId
    })

    const {
        newName,
        newCost,
        newDepartmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName,
        newCategoryId } = formValues

    const handleUpdateItem = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            await axios.put(`${baseURL}${id}`, {
                "id": +id,
                "name": newName,
                "cost": +newCost,
                "department": [
                    {
                        "name": newDepartmentName,
                        "identification": newDepartmentIdentification
                    }
                ],
                "category": [
                    {
                        "name": newCategoryName,
                        "id": +newCategoryId
                    }
                ]
            })
            const modified = await axios.get(`${baseURL}${id}`)
            const { selected } = modified

            dispatch({
                type: types.modify,
                modifiedItem: selected
            });
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Your item has been modified',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                history.push('/')
            }, 1500);

        } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Something went wrong!',
                footer: 'Unable to modify item, who passes the id?'
            })
            return dispatch({
                type: types.error,
                msg: 'Unable to modify item'
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='container mt-5 mb-5 pb-3 bg-light'>
            <form className='mt-3' onSubmit={handleUpdateItem}>

                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Name'
                    placeholder='Name'
                    name='newName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Cost'
                    placeholder='Cost'
                    name='newCost'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCost}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Department Name'
                    placeholder='Department Name'
                    name='newDepartmentName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newDepartmentName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Department Identification'
                    placeholder='Department Identification'
                    name='newDepartmentIdentification'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newDepartmentIdentification}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Category Name'
                    placeholder='Category Name'
                    name='newCategoryName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCategoryName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Category Id'
                    placeholder='Category Id'
                    name='newCategoryId'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCategoryId}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />

                <button className='btn btn-success ' type=' submit'>
                    Modify Item
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and the other:
ConditionalRenderUpdateItem

```
import React from 'react'

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import UpdateItem from '../screen/UpdateItem';


export default function ConditionalRenderUpdateItem() {

    const { selected } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer)

    console.log(selected)

    console.log(selected?.name)
    console.log(selected?.cost)
    console.log(selected?.department[0].name)
    console.log(selected?.department[0].identification)
    console.log(selected?.category[0].name)
    console.log(selected?.category[0].id)

    const id = selected?.id
    const name = selected?.name
    const cost = selected?.cost
    const departmentName = selected?.department[0].name
    const departmentIdentification = selected?.department[0].identification
    const categoryName = selected?.category[0].name
    const categoryId = selected?.category[0].id
    return (
        <div>
            {(selected !== null) &&
                <UpdateItem
                    id={id}
                    name={name}
                    cost={cost}
                    departmentName={departmentName}
                    departmentIdentification={departmentIdentification}
                    categoryName={categoryName}
                    categoryId={categoryId}
                />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

and this is it

EDITING AGAIN DUE TO NEW PROBLEM

As I explained in the comment below, now I have the same issue, populating the form values with previous data...to fix this as suggested by @Drew Reese
I implemented a useEffect this way after extracting also the reset function from my custom hook:

```
const [formValues, handleInputChange, reset] = useForm({

        newName: name,
        newCost: cost,
        newDepartmentName: departmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification: departmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName: categoryName,
        newCategoryId: categoryId
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        reset()
    }, [id])
```

in UpdateItem.js

and this is the custom hook I am using, created by tehacher Fernando Herrera from Udemy:

useForm

```
import { useState } from "react"

export const useForm = (initialState = {}) => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)

    const reset = () => {
        setValues(initialState)
    }

    const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {

        setValues({
            ...values,
            [target.name]: target.value
        })


    }

    return [values, handleInputChange, reset]
}
```

EDITED AS FINAL PIECE OF ANSWER

its also needed to include all the form values as dependencies of the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        reset()
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [id, name, cost, departmentName, departmentIdentification, categoryName, categoryId])
```

Comment: What does "out of phase data" mean? Can you clarify what isn't working as expected? What the issue is?

Comment: **first nothing then updates** and  **I've selected Raspberries and I obtain Cherries as console.log show...and it keeps going** shows what i am talking about...I am refering to the fact that when I choose an item to be updated the form shows empty values but in the console.log it shows the correct data,then I go back and choose another item different to the previous one and then the values that shows in the form are those who belong to the first one...I select one item, the data showed belong to the previous one, thats what I am refering with out of phase, out of sync

Comment: Sounds like a stale state/props enclosure for whatever it is you are rendering. The `setTimeout` in `handleUpdateItem` also seems a little suspect. Can you update your question to show where you are rendering the data that you say isn't showing in the UI, after it's selected?

Comment: handleUpdateItem works fine...the issue is that I need to do something for waiting that the data from selected could be fully loaded, so my initial form values can obtain proper data and not undefined (resulting in my blank form values). imagine that after I select another item to update, the data render in the form is the previous one...but updates ok if I enter new values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and comments are a bit unclear, but it sort of sounds like you need to reset the form data when you've selected a new value and the `state.axiosDataReducer` state has updated.

When it's updated in your redux store the component will rerender and you'll have the latest selected value. There's nothing to wait for, React and redux will provide the updated values to the component.

Memoize the form's initial data values and pass to the hook, and use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `selected` state to call the `useForm` hook's `reset` function. When the `selected` state updates the `useEffect` hook will trigger its callback and the `reset` function will should be invoked and reset the form fields with the latest `initialData` value.

```
export default function UpdateItem() {
  ...
  const { data, selected } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer);

  const { id } = selected;

  const initialData = React.useMemo(() => {
    const selectedItemtoModify = data?.filter(x => x?.id === id);

    return {
      newName: selectedItemtoModify[0]?.name,
      newCost: selectedItemtoModify[0]?.cost,
      newDepartmentName: selectedItemtoModify[0]?.department[0].name,
      newDepartmentIdentification: selectedItemtoModify[0]?.department[0].identification,
      newCategoryName: selectedItemtoModify[0]?.category[0].name,
      newCategoryId: selectedItemtoModify[0]?.category[0].id
    };
  }, [selected]);

  const [formValues, handleInputChange, reset] = useForm(initialData);

  useEffect(() => {
    reset();
  }, [selected]);

  const {
    newName,
    newCost,
    newDepartmentName,
    newDepartmentIdentification,
    newCategoryName,
    newCategoryId,
  } = formValues;
```

Comment: I will try this solution but I've found one. I splitted the component in two, one getting data from store with useSelector and the other in charge of render the form. that gives time to one component to get the data and rendering the other component only if selected!==null..I post my answer. thanks for your help

Comment: @MaykelContrerasCamacho That may also work if you are conditionally remounting the component holding the form data, effectively "resetting" it by mounting a new instance. In fact, this is close to something else I would have suggested if you didn't expose out a "reset" form data function.

Comment: ufff..I have the same problem now...is true that now I can populate the form values with initial data, but when I tried to select another item for update, the previous value populates de form values (again). is the same issue with the main diference that now is not empty values but the real one in the first attempt..is the same out of phase problem!!

Comment: @MaykelContrerasCamacho Think you could try creating a *running* codesandbox of your code that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and live debug in?

Comment: what I did to solve this: addes to UpdateItem.js ```useEffect(() => {
        reset()
    }, [id])```...and now I hope this is the end!!

Comment: better than this, i will publish my repo so everybody could be free to teach me some cool stuff...I will drop out for today. thanks for your time and patience: https://github.com/jotasenator/online-store-challenge

Comment: there is also needed the other variables from the form as dependencies of useEffect

Comment: @MaykelContrerasCamacho Can you be more specific? I don't quite follow that last comment.

Comment: look at the last edit above, in the main question. regards